# Mobile app: CSS for list item that activates on CLICK but not on SWIPE

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, cordova, jquery-mobile

I've created a list of links in my app and I would like to change the background of the link when it is tapped.
If I use the css pseudo class `:active`, the background-color also changes when the user is just touch-scrolling (swiping) the list. I don't want this.

How to make the background-color change only when the link is tapped ?

The rest of this Phonegap app uses Jquery Mobile, but this list doesn't, it uses infinity.js (long list).

Thanks

HTML:

```
<ul id="modelsListview">
 <li><a class="optionfuninit" href="#" data-proid="231"><img class="imageoptionsbrand" src="./images/brands/formulaene.png"><div class="listviewtexts"><span class="listviewtextsmodel">Alien</span> - <span class="listviewtextspro" data-i18n="welcomepage.15">telle que surfée par</span> <span class="listviewtextspro">Dav Rast</span></div><img class="imageoptionsmodel rotate90right" src="./images/boards/FE.png"></a></li>
 ...
 ...
 ...
</ul>
```

CSS:

```
#boardselection ul#modelsListview li a:focus {
    background-color: #06b4c8;
}
```

I tried this:

```
$("#boardselection ul#modelsListview li a").bind("touchend", function() {
            $(this).addClass("fake-active");
        });
```

but it's not satisfying...

Comment: Have you tried `:focus`?

Comment: nope :) trying now...

Comment: Specifically what mobile browsers are you targeting?

Comment: I am using Phonegap Build and targeting iOS and Android.   I just tried and it doesn't show the background-color.

Comment: Can you add your markup and CSS here please?

Comment: done ! I added the markup and css